# How do I get task info / results from a task in another process?

Tags: python, celery

I have this `tasks.py`:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://localhost')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print "Waiting for some time!"
    time.sleep(5)

    return x+y + 10
```

and use this code to fire the task:

```
from tasks import add
import time
from celery.result import AsyncResult

r =  add.delay(4, 4)
id = r.task_id

print "started task: "+id

newresult = AsyncResult(id)

print "ready? "+str(newresult.ready())
```

and it all works fine. The task gets sent to the celery worker and it returns immediately with

```
[bf@localhost CeleryTest]$ python celerytest.py 
started task: e73ad2ab-3ab6-457a-9185-199c4073f99d
ready? False
```

Now, I want to request status of that task from another Python script, so I do this:

```
>>> from celery.result import AsyncResult
>>> from tasks import add
>>> newresult = AsyncResult('e73ad2ab-3ab6-457a-9185-199c4073f99d')
>>> newresult.ready()
False
```

Somehow, this `newresult` is never ready and its result is `None`. How can I query Celery to return a valid `AsyncResult` from another process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fiddled a little with the backend (changed it to `redis://` and it worked), in `tasks.py`:

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://', broker='redis://localhost')
```

Looking a little further into the docs I found:

> The RPC result backend (rpc://) is special as it doesn’t actually
>   store the states, but rather sends them as messages. This is an
>   important difference as it means that a result can only be retrieved
>   once, and **only by the client that initiated the task**. Two different
>   processes can’t wait for the same result.